# Efficient Graph Data structure Python

Tags: python, graph-theory, numpy-ndarray

I have a weighted graph data structure used in a machine learning algorithm, that requires frequent alterations (insertions, deletions of both vertices and edges). I am currently using an adjacency matrix implemented with a numpy 2d array with entries being

```
G[i, j] = W{i, j} if ij (is an edge) else 0
```

This works well for edges |V| < 1,500 but gets really slow with the search, insert and delete operations beyond that.

Since I am using a vectorized optimization of the graph embedding based on the weights, I need to use numpy arrays, so using lists is not feasible in this case.

Is there any efficient implementations of graphs that I can use for the storage, and operations on Graphs written in Python that can used ?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the question, it is very hard to beat the performance of an adjacency list when the graph is sparse. Adjacency matrices will always waste a lot of space for sparse graphs so you will probably have to find an alternative from using numpy arrays in all operations.

Some of the possible solutions to your problem may be:

- Use an adjacency list structures for the other operations and convert to 2d numpy arrays when necessary (may not be efficient)
- Use a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html): try to use a sparse matrix so you still can do matrix operations without converting back and forth. You may read more about them in this [blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/). Note that you will have to replace some of the numpy operations to their scipy.sparse equivalents in your code if you opt for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NetworkX` library which is one of the best out there to handle `Graph` data structures.